# Navigate in Angular 2 Without Having to Click On an HTML Element

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

It is possible to find many examples showing how to navigate between components using a button or a routerLink in angular 2. What I want to do is to navigate to a certain component when an error occurs, without user action. Like this:

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error) {
        this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
    }
}
```

But it is not possible to initialize a Router object in MyErrorHandler constructor. Is there any way to work around this issue and create an auto navigate system?

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about routing in Angular, I have a course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing You can sign up for a free week to watch the course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `Router` service inside your error handler class, you will have to inject it. You can do this by registering your service using the `@Injectable` decorator. See the example below.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler {
    constructor(private router: Router) {

    }

    handleError(error) {
        this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
    }
}
```

After doing this you can inject your `MyErrorHandler` service into your component or any other place you would like to use it.

For more information on dependency injection (DI), see:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: This helped me solve the problem but I had first to inject the injectible service and get the router via injectible. Thanks